# Delphi automation resize chart

Tags: excel, vba, delphi, automation, ms-word

I have a word document that I generate through automation. I need to put a chart (generated in Excel) inside this document, and resize the chart so it would not exceed the margins of the document. How can I do that? Visual Basic does not record this activity when recording a macro, so I have no idea on how to proceed.

Any thoughts?

My approach is:

```
var
MsWord,E:OleVariant;
name:Variant;
...
try
    MsWord := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
  except
    try
      MsWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
      MsWord.Visible := False;
    except
      Exception.Create('Error');
    end;
  end;
MSWord.Documents.Add;
MSWord.Selection.TypeText('some text');
...
E:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
E.Workbooks.Add;
E.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Item[1].Select;
name:=E.Charts.Add.Name;
E.Charts.Item[name].ChartType:=1;
E.ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Item[name].SetSourceData(Source:=E.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Item[1].Range['A1:B6'],PlotBy:=2);

E.ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Item['Chart1'].Select;
E.Selection.Copy;
MSWord.Selection.PasteSpecial(,,,,wdPasteOleObject);
```

So this is how I add to Word a chart generated in Excel.
The only problem is that the chart is too big, I need to make it smaller so it would fit better in the word document without the user interaction

I tried to record the resizing done in word, and the macro says:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes("Object 2").Select
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.81, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.81, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
```

so I tried:

```
  MSWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes('Object 2').Select;
  MSWord.Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth(0.51, 0, 0);
  MSWord.Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight(0.51, 0, 0);
```

However, apparently, for Delphi: `"Shapes" is not a method`
So it does not work this way either.

If I change

```
 MSWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes('Object 2').Select;
```

to

```
 MSWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes['Object2'].Select;
```

then I get: `"Item" is not a property`

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: You might find early bound COM useful here. You at least have an interface declaration which lists all available props and methods.

Comment: You mean using Excel_TLB and Word_TLB ?

Comment: Yes. It does at least make it clear what syntax to use to dig deeper into the object model.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no reference that I could find about resizing in the TLB files. I did search before asking the question...

Comment: The TLB led me to the solution. I looked at the properties and methods of the `Shapes` interface.

Comment: Can you tell me the solution that you found to resize a chart :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the shape like this:

```
MsWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes.Item('Object 2').Select;
```

Comment: If you read my question above, you will see that I already tried that and debugger says: "Shapes" is not a method

Comment: I you read my answer above you will see that my code differs from what you tried.

Comment: My apologies. You are right. And you just saved my day. Thank you